# cosmos db cannot query using IN, spring data native query and array or collection(Java)

Tags: azure, spring-data, azure-cosmosdb, spring-webflux, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to create(using spring native query) the findAllId for the reactive repository spring data cosmo DB.
Since for the ReactiveCosmosRepository is not implemented.

```
@Query(value = " SELECT *\n" +
        " FROM   container_name km\n" +
        " WHERE  km.id IN (@ids) \n" +
        " ORDER  BY km.createdDate DESC ")
Flux<ContainerData> findAllById(@Param("ids") String[] ids);
```

or even

```
@Query(value = " SELECT *\n" +
        " FROM   container_name km\n" +
        " WHERE  km.id IN (@ids) \n" +
        " ORDER  BY km.createdDate DESC ")
Flux<ContainerData> findAllById(@Param("ids") Iterable<String> ids);
```

but it is not retrieving any results, and it is not throwing any exception either.

So the question is, how to use IN operator with spring data native query in cosmos db and collection or array out of the box without having to do a workaround.

Comment: Did you try array_contains ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [array_contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-array-contains)

```
@Query(value = " SELECT *\n" +
        " FROM   container_name km\n" +
        " WHERE  array_contains(@ids, km.id, true) \n" +
        " ORDER  BY km.createdDate DESC ")
Flux<ContainerData> findAllById(@Param("ids") Iterable<String> ids);
```