# Azure Cosmos DB SQL API - @Query

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a Azure Cosmos DB Container 'RouteZipcodes' container. It will have json documents with each route and zipcodes that each route is serving. Below is the sample data stored in cosmos DB

```json
{
  "id": "2347z3e8-850d-364a-92d2-4fcae2fa5642",
  "routeName": "THORN1",
  "zips": [
    { "zipCode": "80373" },
    { "zipCode": "80371" },
    { "zipCode": "80020" },
    { "zipCode": "80370" },
    { "zipCode": "80021" },
    { "zipCode": "80040" },
    { "zipCode": "80602" },
    { "zipCode": "80372" }
  ],
  "status": "A"
}
```

When I execute below query from portal:

```sql
SELECT r.routeName as routeName
FROM routeZipcodes r
JOIN rz in r.zips
where rz.zipCode = "80602"
```

Below is result:

```json
[ { "routeName": "THORN1" } ]
```

When I am trying to run same query from Spring boot app, and am not getting any result. Below is my respository

```
    @Repository
public interface RouteZipcodesRepository extends CosmosRepository<RouteZipcodes, String> {
    
    Optional<RouteZipcodes> findById(String id);
    Optional<List<RouteZipcodes>> findByHubName(String hubName);
    Optional<RouteZipcodes> findByRouteName(String routeName);
    
//  @Query("SELECT r.routeName FROM routeZipcodes r JOIN rz in r.zips where rz.zipCode = \"@zipcode\"")
//  String findByZipCode (@Param("zipcode") String zipcode);
    
    @Query("SELECT r.routeName as routeName FROM routeZipcodes r JOIN rz in r.zips where rz.zipCode = \"@zipcode\"")
    List<IRouteNameByZipcode> findByZipCode (@Param("zipcode") String zipcode);
}
```

other methods are working as expected. Only query written with @query is not giving results when the same was working in portal.

Comment: have you tried ARRAY_CONTAINS? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-array-contains you can refer to this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/67470805/3224238

Comment: or perhaps something like `SELECT r.routeName as routeName FROM routeZipcodes r WHERE r. zips[0]. zipCode IN ("80373")`